# Retrieve php array from ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to retrieve array that was created by php and send back to my JS script via ajax.

I am not sure how to display the value.

server side php

```
 $r=array();
 $r[] = 'aaa';
 $r[] = 'bbb';
 $r[] = 'ccc';


echo json_encode($r);
```

my JS

```
....ajax codes....

var p=document.getElementById('text');

if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

    var r=xmlhttp.responseText;

   for (var i=0; i<r.length; i++){
        p.innerHTML= r[i] + '<br>';
   }
```

}

The output will be

```
a
a
a
b
b
b
c
c
c
//but I want these
aaa
bbb
bbb
```

I want to use javascript instead of $.ajax to complete this. Any ideas?? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Without ajax how could you get the result from server using javascript ? May be I didn't get your question.

Comment: I didn't post the entire codes, but I did send ajax to the server, create my php array and send back to my JS. My problem is having strange output.

Comment: You should `JSON.parse()` the response you get in `xmlhttp.responseText`, it will not magically decode JSON by itself as jQuery does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to parse the json string before, e.g. with [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). Try (untested):

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var r=JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
    for (var i=0; i<r.length; i++){
        p.innerHTML= r[i] + '<br>';
    }
```

=== UPDATE ===

If you have to support very old browsers (e.g. less or equal then IE7) you should use libraries like [Crockfords JSON2parser](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) (a huge lib with much more features).

Comment: Be aware of older browsers, specially ie < 8.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to transfer an array from the server to the client is to use JSON. The following can be used to echo the array in JSON:

```
echo(json_encode($array));
```

See [here](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) for more information.

Then on the client side you can use the following function to decode the JSON to produce the same array:

```
decodedjson = JSON.parse(ajax.response);
```

Don't forget to wrap the client side code in an ajax call.

Hope this helps!